# React Natie, When I use useState data on componentWillUnmount, just getting first data

Tags: react-native

When I use useState data inside useEffect return function (componentWillUnmount), I am just getting first data,

I am changing note values on textview and when i go back another screen, useEffect return function working well but note values is "". Why this happining and how can i solve it?

```
const [note, setNote] = useState("");

 useEffect(() => {
        getContent();
        return () =>{
            saveToStorage({note:note}, "componentWillUnmount");
        };
    }, []);

const saveToStorage = (data) =>{
   console.log(data); // note:""
}
```

Comment: Share complete code what "getContent" is doing?

Answer (score 0):

useEffect will get the note reference only once since you have added [] as dependencies instead give notes as dependencies so it will be called evertime so it can get updated note reference

code:

```
const [note, setNote] = useState("");

   React.useEffect(() => {
    if (condition to check wether its first time) {
      //  getNotes()
    }
    return () => {
      saveToStorage({ note: note }, 'componentWillUnmount');
    }
  }, [note]);

const saveToStorage = (data) =>{
   console.log(data); // note:""
}
```